# C++ , Do While code difference

Tags: c++

I've just started learning C++ and I have a basic question on the difference between two codes.  This is the way it was presented in an instructional video:

```
int main()
{
   bool bPlayAgain = false:
   do {
       PrintIntro();
       PlayGame();
       bPlayAgain = AsktoPlayAgain();
   }
   while(bPlayAgain);
   return 0;
}
```

My question is that I have achieved the same results using:

```
int main()
{
    PrintIntro();
    do { 
       PlayGame(); 
    }
    while (AskToPlayAgain() == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Both achieve in restarting the game when the player inputs Yes if he wants to play again or stops if anything else is inputted. Are there any unwanted side effects in using the second one?

Comment: Did they really format the code like that in your video ? That's pretty shocking.

Comment: Your version doesn't print the intro if the user wants to play again.

Comment: Thank you all for the help , I understand now. And no they do not format it like that in the video , that would be my sloppiness, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second version doesn't print the Intro on every loop. Other than that, there is no side effect of calling `AsktoPlayAgain()` as the while parameter.

I'd like to add that version 1 has the added benefit that you can do stuff after asking but before replaying. For example:

```
int main()
{
   bool bPlayAgain = false:
   do {
       PrintIntro();
       PlayGame();
       bPlayAgain = AsktoPlayAgain();
       if(bPlayAgain){
         ShowReload();
       }
   }
   while(bPlayAgain);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The only side effect that I see is that in your second code snippet, the PrintIntro() function will only be called once. It wont be called everytime the user decides to play again.

Answer (score 4):

There are two functional differences between the two methods:

1. In the second version, PrintIntro() will only be called once rather than before every game.
2. AsktoPlayAgain can return any nonzero value in the first one, but it can only return 1 in the second. (If AsktoPlayAgain only ever returns 0 or 1, this isn't really a difference at all.)

Answer (score 0):

the only unwanted side effects that I see are

- PrintIntro() is only called at the beginning. It won't re-execute if a player decides to play again. Though, this may be your intention.
- You have issues on some systems when casting a `bool` to an `int` in your `while` statement: `while(AskToPlayAgain() == 1);`. AskToPlayAgain returns a `bool` but 1 is an `int`. You could replace that statement with `while(AskToPlayAgain());` and achieve the same effect without issues since a `bool` is returned.